# Why the parameter goes invalid through closure?

Tags: javascript, closures

According to the code snippet, why Fn1 can't get the very beginning parameter "foo"? If I still want to use the form of closure instead of involving a new parameter in Fn3, is there a possibility to let Fn1 has the access to "foo"?

```js
const Fn1 = (txt) => {
  console.log(txt);
}

const Fn3 = (fn, num) => {
  return () => {
    fn(); // undefined
    console.log(num) // 7
  }
}

const Fn2 = Fn3(Fn1, 7);

Fn2("foo"); // undefined, 7
```

Comment: It takes a parameter, which you aren't passing. Pass it one? `fn(num);`?

Comment: The function returned by *Fn3* has a closure to *num*, but *Fn1* doesn't and you don't pass the value, so… *txt* is undefined. Change `fn()` to `fn(num)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers! I've edited the description to clarify that my propose is to use the initial parameter "foo" in some way, if it's possible.

Comment: It's not the `fn` that is undefined but `txt` is undefined: `fn()` <-- here you are not passing in `txt`. By default a value that is not passed in is undefined. You can simulate this by calling `Fn1()` directly. Now compare to `Fn1('testing')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the parameter:

```
const Fn3 = (fn, num) => {
  return (parameter) => {
    fn(parameter);
    console.log(num);
  }
}

const Fn2 = Fn3(Fn1, 7);

Fn2("foo");
```